# Writing text to image in python 2.7 using PIL

Tags: python, image-processing, text, python-imaging-library, image-manipulation

Edit:
Code works however I had

```
draw.text((30,10), "Hello World", (255, 255, 255, 255),font=font)
```

which writes "Hello World" as white. If you change it to

```
draw.text((30,10), "Hello World", (255, 255, 255, 255),font=font)
```

enter code "Hello world" will be written in black.

I have a python script that is trying to write "Hello World" onto a jpg image but when I save the file there is no text written to it, any ideas?
I'm using python 2.7 and Pillow.

I've also had a look at this documentation: http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/ImageDraw.html

Code:

```
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageDraw
from PIL import ImageFont

pattern = Image.open("DANK.jpg", "r").convert('RGBA') 

size = width, height = pattern.size
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(pattern,'RGBA')
font = ImageFont.truetype("Font.ttf", 3)

draw.text((30,10), "Hello World", (255, 255, 255, 255),font=font)
pattern.save('sample-out.jpg')
```

I've also noticed that when the image is saved the colours become gray scale, why might that be?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following code worked for me but I used python 3 and a png. I placed the image in the same directory as the code and then a text was written over the image.

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont
# get an image
base = Image.open('lena.png').convert('RGBA')

# make a blank image for the text, initialized to transparent text color
txt = Image.new('RGBA', base.size, (255,255,255,0))

# get a font
fnt = ImageFont.truetype('Pillow/Tests/fonts/FreeMono.ttf', 40)
# get a drawing context
d = ImageDraw.Draw(txt)

# draw text, half opacity
d.text((100,100), "Hello", font=fnt, fill=(255,255,255,128))
# draw text, full opacity
d.text((100,160), "World", font=fnt, fill=(255,255,255,255))

out = Image.alpha_composite(base, txt)

out.show()
```

I don't have the font, but it also appears to work with python 2.7 and a jpg image just like your code (but I don't have the font)

```
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageDraw
from PIL import ImageFont

pattern = Image.open("DANK.jpg", "r").convert('RGBA')

size = width, height = pattern.size
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(pattern,'RGBA')
#font = ImageFont.truetype("Font.ttf", 3)

draw.text((30,10), "Hello World", (0, 0, 0, 0))#,font=font)
pattern.save('sample-out.jpg')
```

[image]

The most similar to your code (using my Ubuntu 16.04) is the following which also renders text on the image.

```
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageDraw
from PIL import ImageFont

pattern = Image.open("DANK.jpg", "r").convert('RGBA')

size = width, height = pattern.size
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(pattern,'RGBA')
font = ImageFont.truetype("Pillow/Tests/fonts/FreeMono.ttf", 100)

draw.text((300,10), "Hello World", (0, 0, 0, 0),font=font)
pattern.save('sample-out.jpg')
```

[image]

Comment: Hi I realised where I made my mistake, had 
draw.text((30,10), "Hello World", (0, 0, 0, 255),font=font) to write in white rather than in black.

Thanks for your assistance.